# How (if) is the metric of the quantum vacuum different from the metric of the classical vacuum?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, space-expansion, vacuum, qft-in-curved-spacetime

The classical vacuum, with no matter or energy in it, has a flat metric.

Meanwhile we know that the classical vacuum is a chimera. There are lots of things going on, even though it is called virtual. Particles interact by it and we all know the pictures of energy boiling in it, in a variety of colors.

Still, two test masses moving in it, appear to stay parallel, without their distance changing because of it.

But... Have we actually ever encountered a vacuum? The present universe is filled with mass all having influence on the metric.

What if we took all this matter out? Would space inflate like mad? What is the metric of a true quantum vacuum?

Comment: I believe you meant to say that the quantum vacuum is a chimera, rather than the classical one.

Answer (score 1):

The classical vacuum is the classical physical state in which one has $T_{ab} = 0$, $T_{ab}$ being the stress-energy tensor of the matter present in the Universe. I follow the typical convention in General Relativity that $T_{ab}$ includes the cosmological constant term, so that Einstein's equations in a classical vacuum read
$$G_{ab} = 8\pi T_{ab} = 0,$$
from which it follows that the metric of a classical vacuum is characterized by being Ricci flat, i.e., $R_{ab} = 0$. Notice that the Minkowski metric is *not* the only metric satisfying this. The Schwarzschild black hole, for example, is also a vacuum solution of General Relativity which does not have the property you mentioned (two test masses will not remain parallel, since they'll fall in the direction of the black hole). Gravitational waves are also vacuum solutions.

Notice then that even in the classical theory knowing the matter content is not enough to fix the metric. One also needs to know boundary conditions. This is a problem that can also be noticed in Electromagnetism: knowing the charge and current densities is not enough to fix the electromagnetic field, for one also might have radiation coming in from infinity, for example. All of these are manifestations of the fact that the gravitational and electromagnetic fields have degrees of freedom of their own, rather than only being an expression of the degrees of freedom of matter (for the E&M case, see, e.g., the discussions in Wald's [*Advanced Classical Electromagnestim*](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691220390/advanced-classical-electromagnetism), especially sections 1.3 and 5.4).

The question for the quantum situation is even less well-posed. The quantum vacuum is also a state, but what one means by vacuum is no longer clear if we are dealing with quantum fields in curved spacetime (which ought to be the case, since you want to know the metric induced by the vacuum). In flat spacetime, the vacuum of a quantum field theory is defined as the unique Poincaré invariant quantum state. However, in curved spacetime the Poincaré group has nothing special, and this definition crumbles down. There are multiple possible choices of what one could mean by vacuum. In Quantum Field Theory in Curved Spacetime, a "vacuum state" can be any pure, Gaussian (A.K.A. quasi-free) state (also typically chosen to be a Hadamard state, which is a technical condition referring to the state not leading to a singular expectation value for the renormalized stress tensor). This is discussed, for example, in Wald's [*Quantum Field Theory in Curved Spacetime and Black Hole Thermodynamics*](https://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/Q/bo3684008.html). Hence, "the quantum vacuum" is not a wel-defined expression in curved spacetime: many states could still be named "the quantum vacuum".

As an example, this is in the foundations of, for example, the so-called Unruh effect. The Unruh effect consists on the prediction that for a field prepared in the quantum state in which an inertial observer sees no particles, an accelerated observer sees a thermal distribution of particles. The quantum field is prepared in a state that is quite obviously "the" vacuum for an inertial observer, but it does not "look like a vacuum" for an accelerated observer. In Minkowski spacetime, we could single out this state using Poincaré invariance, but it still involves choosing a particular quantum state to be treated as the vacuum.

A way of figuring out the metric in a semiclassical way could then be to employ the semiclassical Einstein equations,
$$G_{ab} = 8\pi \langle\hat{T}_{ab}\rangle,$$
where we simply changed the stress tensor for its expectation value. In this case, the Minkowski spacetime is indeed a solution for the Minkowski vacuum, by which I mean that picking the metric $g_{ab} = \eta_{ab}$ will lead the left side to vanish (the left se is completely classical), and the expectation value of the (renormalized) stress-tensor for the Minkowski vacuum does happen to vanish as well.

Notice that in this case we *do* have matter in the Universe, but in a particular quantum state. If we didn't have any matter at all (i.e., if we didn't put any quantum fields in there), then there wouldn't really be any difference between the classical and quantum vacua, which I don't believe to be the situation you were going for. In the case I presented, you do have fields, so you do have the "dynamic" vacuum you mentioned.

Comment: Isn't the classical vacuum defined as $T_{ab}=0$ , where the stress energy tensor is that of the matter field only? So the vacuum field equations are $R_{ab}=\Lambda g_{ab}$

Comment: @KP99 that is a possible way of thinking about what is vacuum. As I mentioned in the beginning of my answer, I took the view that is usual within the community of GR: the cosmological constant term is part of the stress-energy tensor, i.e., I considered the $\Lambda g_{ab}$ term as being within the definition of $T_{ab}$. In any case, even if one chooses to consider the case in which the EFE become $R_{ab} = \Lambda g_{ab}$, the non-uniqueness issues still hold (for $\Lambda > 0$, one can have Schwarzschild-de Sitter, de Sitter, GWs on de Sitter, etc for example)

Comment: According to Wikipedia, the situation you mentioned is known as lambdavacuum: [Vacuum solution (general relativity)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_solution_(general_relativity))

Comment: Isn't the difference between a QV and a classical vacuum that a QV inflates? In other words, if no matter is present? Wouldn't an isolated piece of QV inflate like mad?

Comment: @Felicia I guess it depends on what precisely you call a quantum vacuum. I don't doubt that some vacua might have that property. However, the Minkowski vacuum doesn't. As I said, there are multiple possible definitions when you are dealing with QFT in curved spacetime. In QFT in flat spacetime, the vacuum is the quantum state annihilated by all annihilation operators (i.e., the state with no "particles"), which as far as I know has a vanishing expectation value for the renormalized stress tensor